# Media graph from XPCOM C++ or how to capture raw video/audio frames?

Tags: firefox-addon, media, mozilla, xpcom

There is neat `getUserMedia` call which provides an [`nsIDOMMediaStream`](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/media/nsIDOMMediaStream.idl) object ([`DOMMediaStream`](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/media/DOMMediaStream.h) effectively). I know that this is a wrapper for [`MediaStream`](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/media/MediaStreamGraph.h)  which is a part of `MediaGraph` API and it is possible to set a listener for notifications about new data on media stream (like new raw captured vide frames). But I can't figure out how can I access it from my C++ binary XPCOM component since I'm including just `nsIDOMMediaStream` interface which is not revealing the details.

Is there any way to obtain captured video frames? How this could be accomplished without media graph?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd think including the appropriate headers, and then casting the `nsIDOMMediaStream` to `static_cast<DOMMediaStream*>(stream)` or `static_cast<DOMMediaStream*>(stream.get())` in case of an `nsCOMPtr` and storing the result into an `nsRefPtr<DOMMediaStream>` variable would be possible?

Comment: hm, don't know if it's a common practice to do so. i'll try, thanks!

Comment: I saw this scheme applied in various other places in the mozilla code. `nsRefPtr` and `nsCOMPtr` both use the same kind of refcounting, so that shoulnd't be an issue. You can of course always see what the MeidaStream related code itself.